# Javascript Gmail API - Encoding/Decoding garbles URL's

Tags: javascript, encoding, gmail-api

I have a string that contains a URL

```js
mailMessage += '<img src=3D"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1aA93WZJOhKMZ8JCmJ4u3ejfGVM_Qe2Uv" width=3D"300" alt=3D"Mountains Picture" style=3D"width:100%; height:auto; display:block; border:none; text-decoration:none; color:#363636; ">\n';

email += mailTo + "\r\n";
email += mailFrom + "\r\n";
email += mailSubject + "\r\n";

email += "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";      
email += "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n";
email += "\r\n" + mailMessage;
```

I then call the gmail api to send the message:

```js
 async function sendMessageGapi_new(){
    var mailRequest = await gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({  
       'userId': 'me',
       'resource': {
          'raw': window.btoa(email).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_')
       }
    });
   console.log(mailRequest);
 }
```

Everything works great

1. The email is sent
2. Once the email is delivered to 'To' address the img link is broken.

[Screenshot of email with broken link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nW0aj.png)

Checking the source it is being rendered as:

[Checking source in gmail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ze9s.png)

[html being rendered in the gmail client side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVfIf.png)

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?e=xportview&amp;id A93WZJOhKMZ8JCmJ4u3ejfGVM_Qe2Uv
```

instead of

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1aA93WZJOhKMZ8JCmJ4u3ejfGVM_Qe2Uv
```

Am I doing something wrong with my encoding?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your question, your showing script, `mailMessage` and your current issue. Can I ask you about the detail of it? And, about `when I pull it up in the gmail client.`, what does this mean?

Comment: `mailMessage` doesn't appear  to be used at all

Comment: I updated the code to show "mailMessage" being included in the email var.

It appears that as gmail decodes my message that it somehow garbles this the URL for the image.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. And, I apologize for my late reply. Now, I noticed your response. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your issue, from your updated question, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of your issue is correct, how about the following modifiaction?

#### From:

```
email += "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
email += "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n";
email += "\r\n" + mailMessage;
```

#### To:

```
email += "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
email += "\r\n";
email += "\r\n" + mailMessage;
```

- When I tested this modification, `<img src=3D"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1aA93WZJOhKMZ8JCmJ4u3ejfGVM_Qe2Uv" width=3D"300" alt=3D"Mountains Picture" style=3D"width:100%; height:auto; display:block; border:none; text-decoration:none; color:#363636; ">` is sent as the HTML body, and I confirmed the correct URL. But, in my environment, I cannot see the image. When `3D` is removed, the image is shown. But, I'm worried that this might not be related to the essence of your this question.